# Android custom advertisements

Tags: android

I want to place my own advertisements on my application. Unlike other android ad sdk, my advertisement would be only just an image banner when clicked, creates a browser intent.
The placement of the ads would be on the bottom of the application just like the ad sdk.

Is that possible? If yes, please tell how.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it is possible, using ImageView with the image ad you want, and `setOnClickListener` to set the action after clicking on the ImageView

Comment: And if you want to change the ad remotly you can make a call from your app to a web page that holds the new ad details e.g: banner and ad url.

Comment: Thank you. But can i place the imageview on top of all views?

Comment: Yes, go for fragment.

Comment: Hello Lalith Mohan, have you solved your problem?

Comment: Will Google allow users to earn revenue like this without using an ad network?